# KeyError: '[7,8] not found in axis'

Tags: python

I tried this code

```
dataset_train=pd.read_csv('___.csv',sep=' ',header=None).drop([7,8],axis=1)
col_names = ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8']
dataset_train.columns=col_names
print('Shape of Train dataset: ',dataset_train.shape)
dataset_train.head()
```

then they show error like this

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-9c1e8c19e8a3> in <module>
----> 1 dataset_train=pd.read_csv('PM_train.csv',sep=' ',header=None).drop([7,8],axis=1)
      2 col_names = ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8']
      3 dataset_train.columns=col_names
      4 print('Shape of Train dataset: ',dataset_train.shape)
      5 dataset_train.head()

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   6659         if mask.any():
   6660             if errors != "ignore":
-> 6661                 raise KeyError(f"{list(labels[mask])} not found in axis")
   6662             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   6663         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: '[7, 8] not found in axis'
```

How can I drop the table from that ?

I have a dummy dataset like this

[image]

The example that I have see before like this

[image]

Comment: You need to use `sep=','` or not provide this argument (because default is ‘,’).

Comment: Your original data has 9 columns, and it becomes 7 columns after dropping, so it does not make sense to assign it with 8 column names.

Comment: even tho i tried to change it to 9,10  that even work they show the same error

Comment: I can't replicate the error you're seeing when using @chenzhongpu suggestion, or dropping the sep arg altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a following line:

```
dataset_train=pd.read_csv('___.csv',sep=' ',header=None).drop([7,8],axis=1)
```

You are putting the value of 1 in axis, which raises the error.

Drop `axis = 1` means that the function deletes some values in columns. Therefore, you must change the value to 0, which means rows. like this:

```
dataset_train=pd.read_csv('___.csv',sep=',',header=None).drop([7,8],axis=0)
```

Nevertheless, if you want to use the option `axis = 1`, you could do this:

```
dataset_train=pd.read_csv('___.csv',sep=',',header=None).drop([6,7],axis=1)
```

How can be possible? Because there is not a value of 7,8 in columns.
Note that `drop` in Pandas get a real value, which means it's not based on
number of indices. Check the option `drop` in official [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Comment: if i try drop([6,7],axis=1) 
they show this KeyError: '[6, 7] not found in axis'
then i try drop([7,8],axis=0)
they show error ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 8 elements

Comment: @William it is because you have just one column. You must change the option `sep=' '` -> `sep=','` or remove this option. From your feedback, I change my explanation as I mentioned.

Comment: FYI, if you open the csv file, you can see the cell that have only several rows and one column. (axis = 0 : rows / axis = 1 : columns)

Comment: i got it now im just fixing just like u said then i have to erase after commas in drop